# In liferay javascript is not working(user actions are not triggering)

Tags: javascript, html, liferay

**HTML:-**

`<button type="button" onclick="alert()">Want a greeting?</button>`

**Javascript:-**

`function alert(){ alert('working...') }`

[refference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1PF5.png)

Comment: Notice also, while `alert` is a predefined name, the preview of the fragment editor _will not execute_ your JS event handlers. That's completely expected, as well as links will be deactivated, so that you don't navigate away from the fragment editor through clicking on your fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Call your function anything other than `alert`. It's a reserved keyword, and the error your code gives you is:

> InternalError: too much recursion

```js
function handleClick() {
  alert('working...');
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="handleClick()">Want a greeting?</button>
```

Comment: In Liferay the script is not working

Answer (score 0):

alert() is a built-in method of JavaScript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

If you change the name of your function that will fix the issue:

```js
function test(){ alert('working...') }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Want a greeting?</button>
```

You *can* override the alert method but you can't recursively call the same function.  The issue you're running into is an infinite recursion, you're calling alert > alert > alert > alert > ...

Something like this would work, though.

```js
window.alert = function alert(message){ console.log(message) }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="alert('test')">Want a greeting?</button>
```

Comment: In Liferay the script is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onclick="click()">Want a greeting?</button>

<script> let click = () => {alert('working...');}</script>
```

Comment: In Liferay the script is not working

Comment: @victor Then I would create a new question with the code with the fixed function name. Make sure you specify what exactly you mean by "not working".

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 